# How to auto start MongoDB process after shutdown on Linux centOS

Tags: linux, mongodb, centos

Problem: MongoDb process shutsdown anytime its manually shutted down with Ctrl + C. When that happens, it stays shutted down until its started again.

What I want: Is there anyway i can have the process auto-start after it has been terminated. Am open for any kind of option.

So far what I've been able to find on google is how to autostart MongoDb on system reboot or on system start.

Also if anyone knows how to listen for a mongoDb shutdown, i can have a script start MongoDb when the shutdown listener runs.

Comment: Look into [Systemd service files](https://www.shellhacks.com/systemd-service-file-example/). You can write and use them to run application and scripts as a system service that runs on boot and restart on crash.

Answer (score -1):

I guess it depends on how you would want to approach this. 
I don't know how your program is designed that you can manually Ctrl+C to terminate the DB, but you can catch the "Ctrl + C" signal in your program. Look up information on SIGINT.

Also, you can create a daemon that checks for the PID-FILE of your DB. Make your daemon infinity test whether the DB PID-FILE exists and -?- do something if it doesn't.

Comment: Ok but do you know anyway i can listen for a mongodb shutdown event ?